# How to get JSON values in ios 7

Tags: ios, web-services

I am creating an app for as existing website. They currently has the JSON in the following format :

```
(
        {
        description = "sky is clear";
        icon = 01d;
        id = 800;
        main = Clear;
    }
)
```

I have tried to get the description values it printed like:

```
(
        description = "sky is clear";
)
```

How can i get particular "description" value without parentheses.

Comment: my values inside the parentheses its possible to get the values inside the parantheses

Comment: The data you show here isn't JSON. It rather looks like the output of an NSDictionary. How did you create the output shown above? You might have had JSON data at one point. Did you already read it into an NSDictionary? It might make sense to show your Objective-C / Swift code as well.

Comment: yes @Codo here i printed dictionary values only.JSON values assign into dictionary.I don't know the parantheses is point out the array now i got the output thank you Codo and Tommy

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They returned datas in Array with Dictionary concept.

To get description,

Assume values are serialized and stored in NSArray...

`[[JSONArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"description"];`

Note:If you get more datas use for loop.And replace 0 with iteration index value.

Comment: This is old-style syntax. You better use the current syntax: `jsonArray[0]["description"]`

Comment: yes..But i mentioned this to understand the concept.